# parsing paragraphs and inserting them as DB record

Tags: regex, parsing, paragraph

I am trying to insert records into mysql database. I have text file with multiple paragraphs, one paragraph has to be one db record.

my database has 5 columns - Occupation, Experience, Department, Insured, Remarks

my text file has following format - I have a perl code watching a directory where these text files are stored. The issue is that there could be two occupation values or just one. Until now when format had just one occupation value I start reading file array from nth index, extract everything with offset of 5 in the loop, making a paragraph a record.

The format wont change, it will be combination of below two paragraphs. How can I take these paragraphs into an array separately for db insert? Thanks! ~Ralph

```
### Start of File
Header

Occupation: Analyst3.
Experience: 7
Department: ZAD6A.
Insured: 0
Remarks: None


Occupation: Analyst2.
Occupation: Engineer-I.
Experience: 4
Department: 50021.
Insured: 0
Remarks: New Hire.

Footer
### End Of File
```

Comment: so what do you want to do if there're two occupations in the file?

Comment: I will concatenate the Occupation values in Occupation field in database..thanks for pitching in Alec!

Comment: So I can have something like ..TextFile1_Arr[0]={Analyst3.,7,ZAD6A.,0,None}...TextFile1_Arr[1]={Analyst2.:Engineer-I.,4,50021.,0,New Hire.}..and so on for textfile2.....textfile3..and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
# split the input string into blocks by one or more empty lines
my @blocks = split /\n{2,}/, $input;

# skip Header and Footer by shifting index of @blocks
# get all the value after ':' in the same block
# merge the 1th and 2nd value of the array for duplicated occupation if size == 6
my @results = map { @{$_} == 6 ? ["$_->[0]:$_->[1]", @{$_}[2..5]] : $_ } 
    map { [/:\s*([^\n]+)/g] } @blocks[1..$#blocks-1];
```

Comment: Thanks Alec..gotta try this..however can this be done using regular expressions? I know number of blocks beforehand(no. of blocks is in filename). So I can loop through no of blocks. Now what best regex can capture a block? Start capture from beginning of Occupation until before next Occupation is encountered? Header and footer are constant across all files.

Comment: try this `$input =~ /(Occupation.+?)(?=\n{2,})/sg;`

Comment: Alec..this is capturing only the last Occupation, skipping every other Occupation.